# Destroying a contextmenu in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I noticed that every time I open and close (by clicking on a menu item or clicking at some area out of the menu) a contextmenu (`Ext.menu.Menu`) the `<div>`s won't get removed from the DOM, they somehow just get invisible.

How to change this?

Comment: I'm not too sure about this but the Ext.menu.Menu has a [`hideMode`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-cfg-hideMode). Change it to 'display'.

Comment: There is a 'closeAction' property on Ext.menu.Menu but this defaults to 'destroy' which should remove the items from the DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this to destroy entire component -

```
listeners: {
     hide:function(menu, opt){
    Ext.destroy(menu);
     }
}
```

But you have to create `Ext.menu.Menu`, when click menu button next time.

Comment: I already create it every time, which is my problem. I end up with a bunch of invisible `<div>`s in my DOM after a while.